# How can I get the quest Pickman's Gift from Hancock if he is my follower?

Tags: fallout-4

The quest Pickman's Gift is given by Hancock in Goodneigbor while he is not yet following you.

The dialogue options change once he's a follower.

How can I get this quest if he is already my follower?

Comment: Good question. I know you can explore the Pickman Gallery and clear the tunnels etc. without any specific quest to do so. I think the trigger for the quest (I thought it was Art Appreciation) is asking Hancock for work, which disappears as a dialogue option when you've recruited him.
You can get Pickman's Gift from Pickman . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I entered the Pickmans gallery and received the quest after rescuing Pickman.

Comment: When I went there, I saw only dead people, including Pickman. :(

Comment: It worked for me fine. You can resurrect Pickman with the resurrect console command.